# The new and original object type in memory reusing

Tags: c++, types

> If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage
>   which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is
>   created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a
>   pointer that pointed to the original object, a reference that referred
>   to the original object, or the name of the original object will
>   automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the
>   new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object, if:
>
> — the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location
>   which the original object occupied, and
>
> — the new object is of the
>   same type as the original object (ignoring the top-level
>   cv-qualifiers), and
>
> — the type of the original object is not const-qualified, and, if a
>   class type, does not contain any non-static data member whose type is
>   const-qualified or a reference type, and
>
> — the original object was a
>   most derived object (1.8) of type T and the new object is a most
>   derived object of type T (that is, they are not base class
>   subobjects).

It is not clear what kind of type is meaning? Dynamic or static type? I think, it is static type, because otherwise the latter restriction makes no sense.

Comment: This question looks similar to another one.. a little bit different perhaps but surely not much :)

Comment: "Type of object" is always unambiguous. You may be thinking of the type of an expression or the type of a variable, but that's not relevant here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both.

The static and dynamic type can only be different when the static type is a base class of the dynamic type, but that case is ruled out by the final bullet.

Comment: I agree, it's basically saying "You can use it to manipulate the object if they're of the same most derived object of type T". Also cfr. §1.8.2

Comment: __The static and dynamic type can only be different when the static type is a base class of the dynamic type_ No, static and dynamic types can be different for any types. Given `int` variable `i`, `reinterpret_cast<float&>(i)` is an lvalue of type `float`, but the most derived object to which it refers (i.e. the dynamic type of an glvalue expression) is of type `int`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: That's forbidden by the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @BenVoigt you mean [basic.lval]/8 _If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined_ ? `reinterpret_cast<float&>(i)` doesn't access anything. Check the definition of "access" https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/defns.access

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: The reinterpret_cast hasn't yet accessed anything, but I assumed you meant to do something with the resulting reference in a way that would make it relevant to this discussion.  The whole "a reference that referred to the original object, ... can be used to manipulate the new object, if".  Well, in your example it cannot, because doing so would violate strict aliasing.